# Поменять стили у сообщений в js-плагине just-validate

Tags: javascript, плагин

Хочу добавить margin-bottom у сообщений, которые появляются, когда поле формы не заполнены при отправлении. Всплытие сообщений реализуется посредством js-плагина just-validate. Помогите, пожалуйста, как добавить это свойство? Ссылка на плагин https://github.com/horprogs/Just-validate

Comment: Ну так повесьте на класс `just-validate-error-label`, в чем проблема?